# Validate inputs in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I validate the input(name and age) below? E.g. not allowing empty inputs, maximum age from 0 to 100 and max length? I just started to look into JavaScript/JQuery today.

```
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
       <div class="textinput">
            <label for="name">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>

        <div class="textinput">
            <label for="name">Your age:</label>
            <input type="text" name="age">
        </div>

        <div class="textareainput">
            <label for="info">About yourself:</label>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="action">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I hope this not a bad question. If it is, please give me the reason for downvote so I can improve my future posts.

Comment: I highly suggest reading a guide on JS. (Hint: you're going to have to modify the HTML and add ids if you want to validate the form in its current state with JS.)

Comment: @d3r1ck I see, I can't disagree with that. Removed that part. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. there are so many libraries (validations) that you can use to validate your script. but if you want do do it in your own way try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<form action="#">
        <fieldset>
           <div class="textinput">
                <label for="name">Your name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="nameid">
            </div>

            <div class="textinput">
                <label for="name">Your age:</label>
                <input type="text" name="age" id="ageid">
            </div>

            <div class="textareainput">
                <label for="info">About yourself:</label>
                <textarea id="textareaid"></textarea>
            </div>
            <h3 style="color:red;font-family:monospace;" id="warning"></h3>
            <div class="action">
                <input type="button" value="submit" id="click">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#click").click(function(){
      $("#warning").text("");
      var namefield = $("#nameid").val();
      var agefield = $("#ageid").val();
      var texarefield = $("#textareaid").val();

      if (namefield == "" || agefield == "" || texarefield == "") 
      {
         $("#warning").text("all field sholud be fill");
      }
      else if (namefield != "" && agefield != "" && texarefield != "") 
      {
         var ageInteger = parseInt(agefield);

         if (ageInteger < 0 || ageInteger > 100) 
         {
            $("#warning").text("age should be between 0 and 100");
         }
         else
         {
          $("#warning").text("");
         }
      }

      else
      {
       $("#warning").text("");
      }

   });
</script>
</html>
```

**this is very basic and simple validation.hope this will help to you.**

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://jqueryvalidation.org/

The HTML doesn't need to be altered. See https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules